# how to connect to mysql server if i'm using 2 routers

Tags: mysql, networking, ip-address

i'm currently testing my vb program and my network set-up is like this (sorry i don't know how to say it properly, but please try to understand)

desktop --wired to--> first router --wired to--> second router -(wireless connection)-> laptop

my laptop is the server and i need connect the desktop to mysql server.

i've tried to enter the the ip address that is being obtained by the second router from the first router but it can't connect.

any solution? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Routers should pass on the ip address of your laptop, so that would be the one to use. Query the second router or do an ifconfig/ipconfig on the laptop to find what this is.

Another thing to check is that all the routers pass through the mysql port, the default is 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess your laptop IP is NAT'ed by the first router. So you need the OUTSIDE address of the first router. This will be the addresses presented at the second router as your (inside) laptop address. Look in the first router's settings to see what address is assigned to it.

Next, the only rule you *should* need is on the second router (we are talking standard config here. Most routers do not prevent OUTGOING requests (i.e. requests coming from your desktop are "outgoing" through the first router, so the first router is already "allowing" that request.  On the *second* router you are going to need to add a rule to allow 3306 (assuming a standard mySQL port) through from the IP you discovered above (the OUTSIDE) ip address of the first router.

Just remember - devices "behind" the router in a NAT config have a different address from the "front" (outside) address of the router. When that happens it is the OUTSIDE address of a given router (in this case router 1) that will be presented to the firewall in router 2.

One more thing - it's possible that your second router is just a rider on the network of your first router (getting an IP through DHCP). In which case it will be as @carlot0820 suggested - your desktop IP is the one you use in the rule of the second router. That's because both the second router and the desktop are on the "inside" network of the first router - which (by default) would not typically prevent traffic between devices on the inside. But to the second router that inside network is on it's Outside" so a rule will be necessary.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i managed to connect my desktop to the server from my laptop by configuring the port forwarding settings on my second router, i added my laptop's ip address and specified the default port (3306).